# How to replace variable inside curly braces with values in different tags in xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am processing an xml file using xslt.

```
<ns1:declarationStatements>
    <ns1:parameterisedEntity>
        <ns2:code>NUTSUPSTATE20</ns2:code>
        <ns2:localeData>
            <ns1:description>
                <![CDATA[** When {s} according to instructions {m}g typically weighs {m}g.]]>
            </ns1:description>
            <ns1:id>20253</ns1:id>
        </ns2:localeData>
        <ns2:specType>FOOD</ns2:specType>
        <ns2:id>6653</ns2:id>
    </ns1:parameterisedEntity>
    <ns1:textParameters>
        <ns1:value>228</ns1:value>
        <ns1:id>68225</ns1:id>
        <ns1:sequence>2</ns1:sequence>
    </ns1:textParameters>
    <ns1:textParameters>
        <ns1:value>cooked</ns1:value>
        <ns1:id>68233</ns1:id>
        <ns1:sequence>0</ns1:sequence>
    </ns1:textParameters>
    <ns1:textParameters>
        <ns1:value>255</ns1:value>
        <ns1:id>68229</ns1:id>
        <ns1:sequence>1</ns1:sequence>
    </ns1:textParameters>
    <ns1:id>133421</ns1:id>
</ns1:declarationStatements>
```

I want to get the text inside `<ns1:description>`  i.e.-

`**When {s} according to instructions {m}g typically weighs {m}g`

But I want {s}, {m} and {m} to be replaced by the values in `<ns1:textParameters>/<ns1:value>`. It should look like -

`**When cooked according to instructions 255g typically weighs 228g.`

I tried doing that by using `<xsl:value-of select="ns0:declarationStatements">` and the manipulating string but it is becoming very tedious and complex.

The number of such braces may also vary. So do we have anything like List or Array in XSLT?

Is there any other way or trick I can use to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: In XSLT 1.0, without the use of any extension function, you can only really do this with string manipulation (using a recursive template). Perhaps you can show the XSLT you have already tried? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the parameters are meant to be inserted in order of their `ns1:sequence` value, I would start by defining a **key** as:

```
<xsl:key name="text-param" match="ns1:textParameters" use="ns1:sequence" />
```

then call the following recursive template with `ns1:description` as the `string` param:

```
<xsl:template name="merge-params">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="i" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, '{') and contains(substring-after($string, '{'), '}')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, '{')" />
            <xsl:value-of select="key('text-param', $i)/ns1:value" />
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="merge-params">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, '}')" />
                <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```